# Allow AJAX Post on.click if a field is not empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, if-statement

There are a number of posts for preventing the default on submit, but this .click already begins with prevent default to perform algorithms on the data before the ajax post.

One field is always required, and this seems to make sense, but has yet to work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#formBtn').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    // some algorithms

    var title = $( "#newTitle" ).val();

    if title.value.length != 0 {
      console.log('there is a title');
      // make an ajax call
      $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        data: AjaxPostData,
        type: 'post',
            url:"http://localhost:4200/api/v1/stories",
            success: successFunction,
            error: errorFunction
        });
    };

  });

}); // doc is ready
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="newTitle">
  <input type="text" class="formFormat" id="newTitle" placeholder="Title Goes Here" />
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn" id="formBtn">Enter</button>
```

Comment: I can completely bypass your if statement and ajax request by pressing enter on the input element.

Comment: Can we see the HTML too?

Comment: Read the console. you have a syntax error.

Comment: @KevinB is correct this is not correct 'if title.value.length != 0 {'

Comment: So is down voting and complaining when someone is posting the best answer they have for the information given.. anyways this is not a forum for trolling so I am out, good luck stack.

Comment: @Tony I have yet to see your answer.. Did someone else downvote it? Would be great to clear this up

Comment: @StackThis, it sounds like a job for whatever you are using for client side validation. my answer simply "asked" if you were using jQuery validation and provided the code that would prevent your ajax from calling if you were. if you are i will undelete it for you but i did not feel it appropriate to leave an answer that people were going to keep down voting.

Comment: @StackThis, BTW.. instead of putting it onClick you should use this, straight from jquery site. it will handle enter and click.. id post it as an edit to my answer but.. yeah.  $( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.stopPropagation();
}); this will watch the form level for a submit event to bubble up.

Comment: well.. event.stopPropagation(); // stop events but submit or event.preventDefault(); //stop the default event

Comment: @Tony am looking to add clientSide validation soon.. am putting together a demo for now.. would you recommend something like this: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Yeah that would be it. Pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have functions defined called `successFunction` and `errorFunction`, then you should just need to fix this line:

```
if title.value.length != 0 {
```

by adding parens and removing `.value` (and maybe using `!==`):

```
if (title.length !== 0) {
```

That should make the code function, but the suggestions made in the comments are worth pursuing as well.